# How to read the given input from text file in C++?

Tags: c++

Input:

10.0.0.5 127.0.0.1 3472

10.0.0.11 127.0.0.1 3000

10.0.0.12 127.0.0.1 3030

code:

```
struct sample{
    string Neighbours;
} input;

int main()
{
string mytext;
 int j=0;
ifstream MyReadFile("/f.txt");
while(getline(MyReadFile,mytext))
{    
  if(j%2==0)
    {
       input.Neighbours=mytext;
    }  
    j++;
}
cout<<input.Neighbours<<endl;
MyReadFile.close();
}
```

I am able to get only the last value that is 10.0.0.12 127.0.0.1 3030 as output. what should I do to read all the data and store them into a variable???

Answer (score 1):

The most C++ way to read a whole file in at once is by using the `<iterator>` library.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("input.txt", std::ios::in);

    std::string str ((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```

The output will just be the whole content of "input.txt".

Explanation:
In this line

```
std::string str ((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
```

you are using the overloaded `std::string` constructor to construct a string using a start- and end-iterator. `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)` returns an iterator to the beginning of `file`, `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()` one to the end by using `std::istreambuf_iterator<>()`'s default return value.